# Error getting count of unique results in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

For defining criteria, I am using the below code piece

```
Conjunction c1 = Restrictions.conjunction();
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("owner", 123));
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("shared", 'N'));
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("cId", 20));

Conjunction c2 = Restrictions.conjunction();
c2.add(Restrictions.eq("shared", 'Y'));
c2.add(Restrictions.eq("cId", 20));

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(c1, c2));
```

Then, I want to fetch the unique results for this criteria.

```
CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
Projection originalProjection = criteriaImpl.getProjection();
ResultTransformer originalResultTransformer = criteriaImpl.getResultTransformer();
Object rowCount = criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

int rc = (Integer) rowCount;
```

However, the code fails at `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()` with an error printed on server logs like this below:

> Info: forcing batcher resource cleanup on transaction completion; forgot to close ScrollableResults/Iterator?

And the exception that comes along is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: That is `Info` message, what is the exception?

Comment: Added to the question, please check. ClassCastException it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably this

```
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("shared", 'N'));
```

Try with this, in both places where you use it (`"` instead of `'`)

```
c1.add(Restrictions.eq("shared", "N"));
```

Comment: To improve your answer you should mention why this change should be made and maybe in addition that the same counts for example ints and longs.

Comment: @Jan It was a character that I was passing to the restriction instead of a string. That was it!  Thanks for asking clarification.